# Recolour a single occurrence of a recurring appointment in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar, conditional-formatting

***Brief*: Recolour a single occurrence of a recurring appointment.**

I have the following recurring appointment:

```
Subject: Maths 104
Date: N/A (series)
Time: Thursday 12pm
Recurring: Weekly (4th March to 6th June)
Importance: Normal
```

I want a single occurrence of this series to be a different colour.

```
Subject: Maths 104 (Test)
Date: 17th April (occurrence in series)
Time: Thursday 12pm
Recurring: Part of series above
           (deviates because of subject and importance change)
Importance: High
```

**I'd like this occurrence to be coloured red in calendar view!**

I tried:

- **Adding a category to the occurrence**: Doesn't work, category is series-only.
- **Conditionally formatting for "Test" in the "Subject" field**: Doesn't work!
- **Conditionally formatting for high importance**: Doesn't work!
- **Replacing the occurrence with new appointment with appropriate changes**: Worked!

I do not like this solution, however, as the appointment is not part of the series; this means I have to check every week when I change the recurring time and location details.

Is there any way to do this in Outlook 2010?

Also, the conditional formatting in Outlook 2010 seems to look at the *series only*; even if the occurrence is different, it will look at the data of the series.
Is there a way around this?

Please help!
Thanks.

P.S: I've Googled for a solution to no avail.

Comment: This questions is confusing. Is the "Test" appointment part of the recurring series previously referenced?

Comment: Thanks. Reading over it made me realise it was a bit of a mess. Is your confusion cleared up? To answer your question directly: I want it to be. The problem I'm having is that I have to remove it from the series to recolour it... making life difficult!

Answer (score 1):

Think of Categories as tags that you can apply to a Calendar item.

- Open the recurring event/meeting.
- It'll ask you Just this one or the Entire series.
- Pick Just this one.
- Delete event/meeting.
- Create a new event/meeting and Categorize/color that one separately.

Tags are applied globally for recurring events/meetings which means the associated color is also applied globally.

You have to make it a distinct event/meeting to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

**It's not possible**

As a workaround, create your own dummy colored appointment as explained by Sun in the separate answer (and optionally delete the corresponding series **occurrence** if you want to see a clean calendar with only one appointment).

NB: tested with Outlook 365 ProPlus - Outlook Version 2002 (Build 12527.21104 Click-To-Run)