# MS Outlook Conditional Formatting Calendar Appointments That Have Text In Message Field

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, conditional-formatting, microsoft-outlook-2016, appointments

I have recurring appointments set up for the ideal time of the day to place orders with our suppliers; we don't always have orders to place, but when we do, I type it up in the text field (I believe this is the Message field) on next individual occurrence & save it for when the reminder pops up.

It would be nice if I can set it up so it only reminds me if there's any text in the message field, but I'd be happy enough if it just changed colors to indicate that said field is not empty. I've been trying to set up conditional formatting to run when the Message field is not empty. It colors every single appointment, even the ones without anything typed up in them, & vice-versa (doesn't color any appointment when set for empty messages). I've tried a bunch of different fields and conditions to no avail. SOS!

Comment: I think you can add different categories which should be convenient.

Comment: Unfortunately, in typical MicroStupid fashion, categories can only be applied to the entire series of appointments. Even if you open an individual one & try to apply it, you'll get an error message stating the fact.

...Which brings to mind that perhaps the reason conditional formatting is applying to the entire series instead of just the individual appointment, is that the "Color" it's applying is actually just a Category; if the condition is true for a single appointment, it sets the category for the entire series.

Comment: I just found a 6-year-old question with a respons that confirms the above: https://superuser.com/q/569321/1049671

Comment: Yes, Outlook doesn't have a built-in option to add different categories to per occurrence of a series. I found this post in Outlook Uservoice forum: https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/322590-outlook-2016-for-windows/suggestions/13924455-enable-categories-for-email-and-calendar-appointme

Comment: In this case, I'd like to recommend you vote the post above and you can submit another post in UserVoice forum about your requirement. It is a place for customers to provide feedback about Outlook. What’s more, if an idea is high voted there by other customers, Microsoft Product Team will take it into consideration when designing the next version in the future.